# Is count_something = len([x for x in blah if x in foo]) or len(set(blah) & set(foo)) too obscure?

Tags: python, coding-style, set, list-comprehension

I use list comprehensions probably about as much as any intermediate or advanced Python programmer.  I try not to use over do it.

I'm curious if this would seem obscure or merely terse:

```
some_count = len([x for x in some_list if x in some_dict])
```

... in lieu of:

```
some_count = 0
for x in some_list:
    if x in some_dict:
        some_count += 1
```

In the actual case I'm looking at I could even use:

```
some_count = len(set(some_list) & set(some_dict))
```

(Given that the items in some_list are guaranteed to be distinct).

In particular I have a function with returns a (possibly empty) list of strings (from an external, proprietary data store).  It should be the case that only one of these is a valid key into a dictionary in my code.  If it's zero I should post a warning, if it's one I should just the the value from my code, and if it's more than one I should emit an error.

I'm just soliciting stylistic opinions here.

Comment: Shouldn't `...if x in some_dict(x)` (in your list comprehension) be `...if x in some_dict`?

Comment: Yes, I'd started writing the question one way and changed how I was trying to present the question.

Comment: I can comprehend the list comprehension version practically instantly, the expanded form fairly quickly and the set version quickly (I use such set operations in such ways quite often).

Comment: Your code employs a *minimal* complete (= including a filtering criterion) list comprehension. If *that* is too obscure then you cannot use list comprehension at all. So the question is moot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition `x in some_dict(x)` is very obscure; looks like you need to lose the `(x)`.

You don't need to build a list; try this:

`some_count = sum(1 for x in some_list if x in whatever)`

Your set approach seems to be the most understandable. It's not likely to be the fastest, however.

Comment: Sorry that was supposed to be some_dict; I'd started to write it as some_test(x) ... but as I edited my question I resolved to clarify that as in some_dict since that's the actual test I was performing.

Comment: I keep forgetting that I can return a constant (such as 1) for my list comprehension.  I'm so used to returning either the items or some derivative of those items other than a simple constant.

Comment: You could also write the latter as `sum(x in dic for x in lst)`

Answer (score 0):

If you really just want to test if there are zero, one, or more than one elements of a list in a dict, you don't have to walk the whole list. This might save some time if the list is huge and there are a lot of (or some early) hits.

```
>>> def f(lst, dic):
...     it = iter(lst)
...     if any(x in dic for x in it): 
...         if any(x in dic for x in it):
...             print("twice or more")
...         else:
...             print("exactly once")
...     else:
...         print("not at all")
...         
>>> f([1, 2, 3], {0:0})
not at all
>>> f([1, 2, 3], {0:0, 1:1})
exactly once
>>> f([1, 2, 3], {0:0, 1:1, 2:2, 3:3})
twice or more
```

Comment: Yes, that's true.  However, in this case there will never be more than a handful of them (due to the nature of the real-world entities involved.  They are servers and this is a list of the clusters in which they are members.  Warning if you attempt to apply this command to things that are in one of these clusters, error if any of them are members of more than one of these clusters as they are intended to be mutually exclusives.  Only a few hundred clusters and very few hosts in more than one, none in more than a handful.